# WPF MVVM DataTrigger not working

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datatrigger

I've just started using Data Triggers so I apologies if it is something simple, but I cant get my Data Triggers to work. Could it be because I have a Command Binding as well ?

```
<Button x:Name="logOnButton"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="369,70,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" IsEnabled="True" Command="{Binding LogonButtonClick}">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="Log On"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LoggedOn}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="Green"/>
                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="Log Off"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LoggedOn}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="Red"/>
                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="Log On"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

Comment: Does your `LoggedOn` property use `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: Yes it does but I havent explicitly invoked it as my understanding is this is automatic

Comment: The LoggedOn property setter must fire the PropertyChanged event when the property value changes (after the backing field has beed set).

Comment: I see that your default control properties are the same as if `LoggedOn = False`, is the second `DataTrigger` firing? If so, I would follow Clemens advice and fire the event in the `LoggedOn` property setter.

Comment: And of course the second DataTrigger is redundant, because it just sets the values that are already set by Style Setters. Moreover, `Property="Control.Background"` should simply be `Property="Background"`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I had to fire the PropertyChanged manually, I thought this was done automatically. once I did that all works OK.